# How to make a field mandatory if we're selecting a particular picklist value

Tags: validation-rule

I want to make 'Date' field mandatory if I have 'Level 1 = Points' and under this 'Level 2 = Redemption'
Level 1 is a controlling picklist for level 2.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/390546/edit) your question to add what you have tried (it's OK if it fails) and how it is not working (e.g., *exact* error text). This site exists to *help*, not do the work. (From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center: *"We’re not a place to exchange code or find implementation services."*) Please read more of the Help Center, and also take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this using validation rule

Just add this condition and you will be good.

> ISBLANK(Date field api name) && TEXT(Level1 )= 'Points' && TEXT(Level2)
> ='Redemption'